# JAXB - generating classes from XSD - converting enums to strings

Tags: java, jaxb

Using JAXB, we generate our Java beans directly. In the XSD, we have an enumerated type:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="promptBeforeCloseType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="default"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="always"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="never"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

JAXB generates an enumerated type for the field using this type. We would like to have it converted to a String in the generated Java class, because those classes are mapped to ActionScript classes, and there is no enumerated type in ActionScript.

Is there a way to do it, implementing some kind of converter ? May be with [XmlJavaTypeAdapter](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html) ?

Comment: You can always use the `toString` or the `name` methods of the enum, surely? :-)

Comment: The generated classes must have a field of type "String" and not "Enum", in every other case the mapping with the corresponding ActionScript class fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force XJC to not generate enums. See the "Global Binding Declarations" section of [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html#bnbcd):

> If typesafeEnumBase is set to
>   xsd:string, it would be a global way
>   to specify that all simple type
>   definitions deriving directly or
>   indirectly from xsd:string and having
>   enumeration facets should be bound by
>   default to a typesafe enum. **If
>   typesafeEnumBase is set to an empty
>   string, "", no simple type definitions
>   would ever be bound to a typesafe enum
>   class by default.**

Comment: updated doc location: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html#bnbcd

Comment: Is this still valid? Because I am setting `typesafeEnumBase` to empty string `""` and I get errors (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927872/jaxb-bindings-set-typesafeenumbase-to-empty-convert-enumerations-to-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Overriding the Datatype][1] section of the JAXB tutorial.  You can do this with a customised bindings file set up similar to the example at the bottom of the page.

I think you'd have to write your own conversion method (and thus class) unfortunately since there doesn't seem to be one built-in (likely due to the fact that the JAXB-generated enums have no common superclass).  But all you'd need to do is call the `value()` method on your enum object, which will return the String that mapped to it.

[1]: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/section_5_6_1-Overriding-the-Datatype.html#Overriding the Datatype

Answer (score 1):

jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumBase="xs:boolean" will work - leaving it blank as suggested is not valid for the binding schema.