# JAXB bindings - set typesafeEnumBase to empty (convert enumerations to strings)

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

According to the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbbf.html#bnbcd)

> If typesafeEnumBase is set to xsd:string, it would be a global way to
>   specify that all simple type definitions deriving directly or
>   indirectly from xsd:string and having enumeration facets should be
>   bound by default to a typesafe enum. If typesafeEnumBase is set to an
>   **empty string, ""**, no simple type definitions would ever be bound to a
>   typesafe enum class by default. The value of typesafeEnumBase can be
>   any atomic simple type definition **except xsd:boolean** and both binary
>   types.

So I have set to my `binding.xjb` the following:

```
<jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumBase=""/>
```

and when running the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` I get the following exception:

```
lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 46; cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type '#AnonType_typesafeEnumBaseglobalBindings'.
...
lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 46; cvc-attribute.3: The value '' of attribute 'typesafeEnumBase' on element 'jxb:globalBindings' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'.
```

As  far as I understand I cannot set the empty string `""` to `typesafeEnumBase` even though the documentation says so. Documentation also mentions that it cannot be `xsd:boolean`.

All I want is to convert the following to `String` instead of `enum`

```
<xs:simpleType name="phraseID">
    <xs:restriction base="escapedStringUserType">
        <xs:enumeration value="NOT_SPECIFIED"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="X000-9999"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="X000-9998"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

A relevant SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680760/jaxb-generating-classes-from-xsd-converting-enums-to-strings) but since I cannot set the empty string `""` or set the `xsd:boolean` value to `typesafeEnumBase` none of the answers work for me (tried both).

Comment: I think the documentation you quoted is poorly worded and does not really say that it is possible to set `typesafeEnumBase` to an empty string - it's as if it is describing a hypothetical situation (judging from the use of the word "would"). The [JAXB specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) says nothing about this so I guess that means that this is not something that is supported.

Comment: @Jesper, thanks for replying, any other solution to generate Strings instead of enums?

Comment: It is possible to use `<jxb:typesafeEnumClass map="false"/>` for specific simple types with enumeration restrictions, but I don't see a way to set it for all these types globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the following

```
<jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="0"/>
```

will not generate any enums for all simple types with enumeration restrictions instead will convert them to strings, however it spits out warnings in the console like the following:

```
Simple type "xxx-address" was not mapped to Enum due to EnumMemberSizeCap limit. Facets count: 10, current limit: 0. You can use customization attribute "typesafeEnumMaxMembers" to extend the limit.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify for a specific simple type with enumeration restrictions that you do not want it to be mapped to a Java `enum` like in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <jaxb:bindings
            schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" 
            node="/xs:schema/xs:simpleType[@name='phraseID']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass map="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But as far as I know, there is no way to set this globally for all simple types with enum restrictions (you cannot use `<jaxb:typesafeEnumClass map="false"/>` directly inside a `<jaxb:globalBindings>`, for example).

(If someone knows how to do this, I'd like to know as well, so please comment or answer).

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, however as you already stated it cannot be applied globally, each simple type with enumeration restrictions must be declared. I found out that `<jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="0"/>` will apply to all simple types with enumeration restrictions and convert them to strings, however it will procuce `warnings` in the ouput. I will upvote your answer but will also post another answer because `<jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="0"/>` is what I exactly need. Thanks a lot for helping me.